# Install boost version 1.40 from terminal

Tags: 12.04, installation, command-line, libraries, boost

I am using a server running with Ubuntu 12.04

I want to install the boost libraries in it. I know

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

will make the work done, but it installs the latest version version 1.52 or above.

But I need to install the particular version 1.40 as there is a problem in a simulator which I am using for my academic purpose. What is the particular command for that so that I can install the boost libraries along with the other requirements for it like the linking files

In particular is there command to select the version like for gcc we can use

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.5
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, determine the available versions you can install with the following command (use for *packagename* the name of the program that you want to install):

```
apt-cache showpkg [packagename]
```

Next, run the `apt-get install` command and specify the package version you want to install (use for *version* the version number previously determined of the program that you want to install):

```
sudo apt-get install [packagename]=[version]
```

After it's installed, run the following command to hold your installed version, preventing the package manager from automatically updating it in the future:

```
sudo echo "[packagename] hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Source: [How to Downgrade Packages on Ubuntu](http://www.howtogeek.com/117929/how-to-downgrade-packages-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: apt-cache is returning only libboost package 1.48