# Install old version of boost

Tags: compiling, boost

I am trying to compile this program called Doppia and it requires an older version of Boost (somewhere around 1.54 - 1.55) however when I try to install it using

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

it installs the latest version while

```
sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev=1.55.0.2
```

does not find any package.
Is there any way to install an older version of a package without having to re-compile it?

Thank you.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I'm using Xenial

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 has boost_1.54 : By adding `deb [url] trusty main universe`  and  `deb [url] trusty-updates main universe` to `/etc/apt/sources.list`,  you can get the libboost-*1.54-dev packages (But not libboost-all-dev=1.54.0.1) . Note 1 : Run `sudo apt-get update` . Note 2 : All '1.54-dev' packages are visible in 'synaptic'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/787601/fetch-specific-boost-version-with-apt-get or http://askubuntu.com/questions/353601/install-boost-version-1-40-from-terminal

Comment: I think compiling Boost from source is the most painless way to go forward. I would refrain from mixing packages from older Ubuntu versions.

Comment: I was able to install that using the ubuntu archives deb url, however it is still installing all the *new* dependencies. Is there any way for apt-get to install the dependencies corresponding to the version that I want? I am afraid installing an older libbost with new dependencies will rise up issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for the package on [www.ubuntuupdates.org](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org), e.g I needed this outdated library

https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/focal/main/base/libboost-program-options1.71.0

Furter down the page there are URLs, i.e. for the 64 bit version as a deb.

1. `wget <filename>` that file to a local directory
2. `sudo apt-get -y install <debname>`

And at least in my case a certain package demanding a slightly outdated libboost package (and not accepting the more recent one) was happy.